# How Convolutional Layers connect to Fully Connected Layers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have designed a CNN in MATLAB with the next set of layers:

[image]

So, if I'm correct making my calculations, the output size of the last ReLU layer should be 7x7x32, which seems to be correct because that size contains 1568 values, and if we look at the Fully Connected Layer, we can see that the vector of weights has size 10x1568:

[image]

Now, I'm making a project where I'm coding the same CNN by hand. But when I have to code the Fully Connected Layer, I don't know how its vector of weights is related to the previous output. For example, I guess that a hypothetical output(1,1,1) value is connected to the weights Weights(:,1). But what about the others?.

My question therefore is, how should I loop through the output to match the weights from the first one (1) to the last one (1568)?.